# Cannot compile Haskell

Tags: windows-7, command-prompt

I'm trying to simply print out a "Hello, World!" message in Haskell.

Here's what I'm doing:

On a text editor, I wrote:

```
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

Saved it with the filename helloworld.hs

In Command Prompt (using Windows 10), I wrote the following:

```
$ ghc --make helloworld
```

But I get the following error message:

```
<interactive>:2:1:
     parse error on input `$'
     Perhaps you inteded to use TemplateHaskell
```

Should I import the helloworld file into ghci before trying to compile it? I tried it but still got the same error.
Also tried including the file extension on the compile line, no luck either.

**### EDIT ###**
Thanks alot to Carsten, Fraser, Sarah and Jakub Daniel.
The problem was with the $ sign. Omitting it solved the error and now I can compile it.

In case someone is having the same problem as me, ommiting the $ will solve the problem for both **compiling** and for **running** the program.

So instead of

> $ ghc --make filename

and

> $ ./filename

try

```
ghc --make filename
```

and

```
filename
```

Yep, after compilation, all you have to do is write the name of the file that you want to run.

Comment: I have a hard time seeing where the `$` is from (also the `$` in your prompt is strange ... windows should not show it) - are you sure that your `helloworld.hs` looks like this?

Comment: Yep. So it appears I have to ommit the $ sign. However, I was only able to compile it once. I closed the prompt, and tried it again, this time I get no message at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put `$ ghc --make helloworld` into GHCi, put it into the Windows command prompt without launching GHCi first (without the leading `$` – this is typically used to signify that what follows is to be entered into the prompt). If you want to load the module into GHCi, use `:l helloworld`.

Comment: Presumably, unless Windows does things differently, they don't want to enter the `$ ` at all.

Comment: Thanks. So I omitted the $ sign, and it appears to work.

"[1 of 1] Compiling Main ( helloworld.hs, helloworld.o )
Linking helloworld ..." which is the message I was looking forwardt to.

However, I closed the command prompt. If I try to do it again, I no longer get that message but I don't get error message either. Is it suppose to compile one time only?

Comment: yes, unless you change the source file and then compile it again

Answer (score 1):

You should not put the symbol `$` in front of your commands, that normally signifies that the following string is a shell command or whatever they are called on windows. So just type `ghc ...` in command prompt in the directory where you keep the file.

Comment: Thanks. So I omitted the $ sign, and it appears to work. "[1 of 1] Compiling Main ( helloworld.hs, helloworld.o ) Linking helloworld ..." which is the message I was looking forwardt to. However, I closed the command prompt. If I try to do it again, I no longer get that message but I don't get error message either. Is it suppose to compile one time only?

Comment: The compiler compares modification times of the produced binary as well as the source and if it hadnt changed it does not compile again

Comment: Thanks once again, Jakub.